# Display attachment image in Angular template

Tags: visualforce, attachment

I'm using the following snippet to display an attachment inside an angular view template:

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
    <img ng-src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, {{d.AttachmentId}} )}">
</div>
```

But when my page loads, the image attachment is not dieplaying. and when I inspect it I see the following:

```
<img ng-src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, 00Pi000000T7tJ6EAJ )}">
```

So the Id is being returned correctly but I'm not seeing it. Could anyone point out the issue here?

I've also tried:

```
<img src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, d.AttachmentId )}">
```

But in thsi case I was seeing the following in my DOM:

```
<img src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, d.AttachmentId )}">
```

So the attachment id wasn't actually returning properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{! }` expression is evaluated at the server-side providing it is a Visualforce page of component that is being output whereas the `{{ }}` expression is evaluated at the client-side in the browser. The two don't mix well and your Angular app will be cleaner if you stick to just client-side evaluation as much as possible.

From what you are seeing the `{! }` is not being processed which makes sense if your template is e.g. in a static resource. A solution to getting Visualforce expressions evaluated is to do that evaluation in the index page (that you make a Visualforce page) and then add the resulting JavaScript object to the Angular app as a constant. That pattern is illustrated in this blog post [Passing platform configuration to an AngularJS app](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/passing-platform-configuration-to-an-angularjs-app/).

For your attachment download, you may end up just having to hard code the `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=` somewhere (but make sure you define it in one place only) and rely on that not changing anytime soon. Or you can write your own `@RestResource` end point and use that.